# в массиве содержатся разные элементы

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

Вот код:

```
int *p;

// так как в функцию указатель в таком виде передать нельзя: компилятор заругается, то:

p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); // в функции я переопределю его размер через realloc

func(p);

for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    printf("%d ", p[i]); // возвращает мусор
/* если из функции делать вывод, то в консоль выводятся корректные значения */
```

Помогите понять, в чём тут дело ?

Прототип функции `func`:

```
void func(int *arr);
```

Делать `int *` не хочу пока что: хочу понять, что тут не так...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67031/discussion-on-question-by-setplus-----).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Итак, у вас есть указатель `int* p;` и вы хотите инициализировать его через вызов функции. Можно сделать так:

```
    void func(int** inPtr){
        int* tmp = (int*)malloc(0x100);
        *inPtr = tmp;
//(*inPtr)[2] = 0x02;//пишем 3-й элемент
    }

    void main(void){
        int* p;
        func(&p);
//printf("0x%X\n", p[2]);//читаем 3-й элемент
    }
```

func принимает указатель на указатель на int, то есть адрес указателя на int. В main мы через ссылку получили адрес нашего указателя и передали его в функцию. В функции мы через разыменование из адреса получили сам указатель и записали в него выделенный буфер.

Пляски с tmp нужны, чтобы в отладчике можно было посмотреть реальный адрес выделенного буфера и сравнить его с тем, что будет в p после выполнения funс()

Comment: Спасибо большое за объяснение, но возник вопрос: разве правильнее писать не `int *p;` и т. д. везде, подчёркивая, что это указатель, а не тип данных такой?

Comment: @Setplus Не знаю. Я видя int* foo; понимаю, что это переменная с именем foo, а тип у нее "int pointer", то есть указатель на целое. Привык, сам себе объяснил, работает как надо.

Comment: а как тогда трактовать `int** ...`?

Comment: @Setplus (int pointer) pointer, то есть указатель на указатель на целое, как я и написал :-)

Comment: Ну вот меня как начинающего и обучающегося по книжке Кернигана и Ричи, смущают подобные штуки :)

Comment: `void*` - указатель на что угодно.

Comment: @Setplus надо не смущаться и быть смелым и веселым

Comment: @Setplus один раз в отладчике в ассемблерных инструкциях посмотрите, как работают указатели, ссылки, разыменование и т.п. Что где реально хранится и куда пишется. Потом проблем не будет, скорее всего.

Comment: Позвольте, я резюмирую. Мы записали сейчас в функции значения по адресу, в котором располагается адрес на `p`. Если так, то в `main` я, чтобы обращаться с элементами массива (друг за другом следуемыми адресами), должен производить разименонвание?

Comment: @Setplus в приведенном мной примере мы ничего не записывали. Можно написать вот так (*inPtr)[2] = 0x02; к примеру в func и тогда 3-й элемент массива станет равен двум. Мы через разыменование получили указатель на int, использовали указатель как "базу" для массива, получили адрес 3-го элемента и записали в него значение.

В main обращение к нему будет делаться так, например:
printf("0x%X\n", p[2]);

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, я почему так говорю: сделал всё, как Вы написали, но вот вывожу содержимое `p` после вызова функции, и там мусор..(

Comment: @Setplus Я привел фрагменты рабочего кода, который у меня прекрасно работает. Если у вас выводится мусор вы делаете что-то не то.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, `int *p; p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); func(&p); for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) printf("%d  ", p[i]);` При первом же заходе в цикл программа вылетает..в функции самой всё в точности, как у Вас.

Comment: @Setplus не верю. Без вашего полного кода толку все равно нет об этом говорить.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, я могу Вам в чате фрагмент выслать?

Comment: @Setplus задавайте отдельный вопрос с полным(!) кодом и пояснением чего вы от него бедняги хотите.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, хорошо, сейчас.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, всё проверил более внимательно. Вы оказались полностью правы, я там копировал данные с помощью `memcpy` не в `*p` а просто в `p` :)

Answer (score 0):

Я не очень понял, почему нельзя передать указатель в функцию и что за мусор получается, по этому попробую просто ответить примером:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define COUNT 15

void func(int *arg)
{
  if((arg = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * COUNT)) == NULL)
    printf("allocation error\n");
} 

int main()
{
  int *p, i;

  // почему в таком виде нельзя передать?
  func(p);

  // если в func() произошел allocation error, будет ошибка, 
  // т.к. мы ничего не узнаем об этом

  // меняем мусор на что-то осмысленное
  for (i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
    *(p + i) = i;


  // выводим массив
  for (i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
    printf("%d ", p[i]);
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: в func утечка памяти, в циклах в main разыменовывание неинициализированного указателя

Comment: @mymedia поподробнее, пожалуйста? Как можно добиться segfault при таких костылях? Буду благодарен, если объясните.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9StEc.png

Comment: @mymedia https://i.imgur.com/JfUMgYj.png
или вы что-то изменили? я не заметил, возможно.

Comment: Не-а, я ничего не менял. Это просто неопределённое поведение - в одном случае работает, в другом - нет. Вам надо исправить, чтобы в func передавался бы адрес указателя, а не само значение указателя. Смотрите пример в ответе Владимира Мартьянова.

Comment: @mymedia либо инициализировать ранее и realloc?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67016/discussion-between-mymedia-and-n3r0bi0m4n).